# When using the dictionary feature in vim, can you make dashes a matching part of a word?

Tags: autocompletion, dictionary

The dictionary feature in vim allows you to use a file (for instance `/usr/share/dict/words`) and set multiple paths within the `dict` option to search on.

Now the file I'm searching on has several words with `-` in them, and I still wish to match after the `-` after activating autocomplete, so is there a way to make the `-` a matched character within the `dict` feature?

Comment: I think that `set iskeyword+=-` should do what you want. See [`:h 'iskeyword'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27). I'm not posting this as an answer because I can't test it right now so let me know if that work?

Comment: @statox I tried it and that did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option `iskeyword` defines which characters should be considered as part of a word. This option uses the `+=` and `-=` syntax to add or remove some characters. Thus the following line will add the character `-` in the option and will allow you to complete words containing a `-`:

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

Comment: If you want to change `iskeyword` just for a particular file type (eg CSS and SCSS), run something like: `autocmd FileType css,scss setlocal iskeyword+=-`

Comment: @Flimm I would advise to create a custom ftplugin instead ([`:h ftplugin-overrule`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule)) using an autocommand is just reimplementing the ftplugin mechanism.